# Ceph single node pool to multiple node

Tags: ceph

If I have a single Ceph node pool already in production, then the pool's setting is based on a single node. I then add another node by pvecm add cluster-ip.

After adding the new node and have Ceph complete installing the osd, could I change the pool parameter to add to it the new node's resources? I did not find a guide to changing the pool settings after containers and vms have used it.